# Country flags after ng build

Tags: angular

I have a question a little curious, after doing a ng build --prod, my dist folder generates the files, but also a lot of flags in SVG format, does anyone know why?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RQXG3.jpg)

Comment: did you find out any reason?

Answer (score 1):

I think it has something to do with the 3rd Party modules you might have imported in your App. Can you share your package.json for more information?

Answer (score 0):

This is my package.json

```
{
    "name": "sosapazfront-end",
    "version": "0.0.0",
    "scripts": {
        "ng": "ng",
        "start": "ng serve",
        "build": "ng build",
        "test": "ng test",
        "lint": "ng lint",
        "e2e": "ng e2e"
    },
    "private": true,
    "dependencies": {
        "@agm/core": "^1.0.0-beta.6",
        "@angular/animations": "~7.2.0",
        "@angular/common": "~7.2.0",
        "@angular/compiler": "~7.2.0",
        "@angular/core": "~7.2.0",
        "@angular/forms": "~7.2.0",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "~7.2.0",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~7.2.0",
        "@angular/router": "~7.2.0",
        "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^4.1.3",
        "@types/jspdf": "^1.3.1",
        "angular-tree-component": "^8.4.1",
        "angular2-text-mask": "^9.0.0",
        "babel-loader": "^8.0.5",
        "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
        "core-js": "^2.5.4",
        "jquery": "^3.4.1",
        "jspdf": "^1.5.3",
        "jspdf-autotable": "^3.2.4",
        "lodash": "^4.17.15",
        "ng2-currency-mask": "^5.3.1",
        "ng2-order-pipe": "^0.1.5",
        "ng2-search-filter": "^0.5.1",
        "ngx-mask": "^7.9.10",
        "ngx-pagination": "^3.2.1",
        "ngx-perfect-scrollbar": "^7.2.1",
        "ngx-print": "^1.2.0-beta.3",
        "ngx-select-dropdown": "^1.0.1",
        "ngx-socket-io": "^2.1.1",
        "popper": "^1.0.1",
        "rxjs": "~6.3.3",
        "sweetalert2": "^8.11.4",
        "tree-ngx": "^3.1.2",
        "tslib": "^1.9.0",
        "xlsx": "^0.15.1",
        "zone.js": "~0.8.26"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.13.0",
        "@angular/cli": "~7.3.8",
        "@angular/compiler-cli": "~7.2.0",
        "@angular/language-service": "~7.2.0",
        "@babel/core": "^7.7.2",
        "@babel/preset-env": "^7.7.1",
        "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.8",
        "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
        "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
        "codelyzer": "~4.5.0",
        "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
        "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
        "karma": "~4.0.0",
        "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
        "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
        "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.2",
        "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
        "protractor": "~5.4.0",
        "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
        "tslint": "~5.11.0",
        "typescript": "~3.2.2"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@carlos, out of curiosity, I used your package.json and created a new project where I also did ng build --prod but didn't get any Flag svgs. Can you please check again your global.scss or any other font imports in scss or index.html?